# How to read array and enum data on swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums, enumeration

how to read these three type of data on swift
I want to assign these three variables to labels. How do I do it?
[**This is the first time, coding with swift, I am a learner, I am very beginner in IOS mobile developing**]

**student.swift**

```
    class Student{
        let nubmers: [phone_number]? 
        let bday: DOB?
        let gender: Gender?

        init(numbers:[phone_number],bday:DOB, gender:Gender){
            self.nubmers = []
            self.bday = bday
            self.gender = gender
       }
    }

enum Gender{
    case Male
    case Female
    case Unspecific
}
```

**phone_number.swift**

```
import Foundation
    struct phone_number {
        var number:String!
    }
```

**DOB.dart**

```
import Foundation

struct DOB {
    let year:Int!
    let month:Int!
    let day:Int!
}
```

**insert data like this? Is it correct?**

```
 let student1 = Student(
             numbers: [phone_number(number: "0773024962")],
             bday: DOB(year:1996,month:01,day:13),
             gender: Gender.Male)
```

**I want to read like this //Error**

```
 func setStudent(student: Student){
         label.text = numbers.number
         label.text = student.bday
          label.text = student.gender
     }
```

Comment: label.text = numbers.number, 
is this supposed to be student.numbers ?

Comment: To access the first phone number you need `student.numbers.first?.number`

Comment: why -2? isn;t it good question? why is that?

Comment: You could improve your question by describing what the error *is*, rather than simply stating that there is an error.  (I didn't down-vote).  Also, it won't cause your problem, but using implicitly unwrapped optionals in your `DOB` struct isn't necessary, and Why not simply use a `Date` for date of birth?  Similarly, wrapping a `String` in a struct for your `phone_number` seems unnecessary.  Swift style uses capitalised camel case for structs and classes and not _, so it should be `PhoneNumber`

Comment: @DarwinHarianto no. Error message Cannot assign value of type '[PhoneNumbers]?' to type 'String?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refer to the first phone number then you need

```
label.text = student.numbers.first?.number
```

I can suggest a couple of other improvements:

- Using implicitly unwrapped optionals in your DOB struct isn't necessary - The initialiser ensures that they will have values
- Why not simply use a `Date` for date of birth?
- Similarly, wrapping a String in a struct for your phone_number seems unnecessary.
- Swift style uses capitalised camel case for structs and classes and not _, so it should be `PhoneNumber`
- Enumeration cases should start with a lower case letter
- You can use a struct rather than a class for `Student` - You are using `let` properties, so you already have immutability. A struct gives you automatic initialiser generation

```
struct Student {
    let numbers: [String] 
    let bday: Date
    let gender: Gender
}

enum Gender {
    case male
    case female
    case unspecified
}

var dc = DateComponents()

dc.setValue(13, for: .day)
dc.setValue(1, for: .month)
dc.setValue(1996, for: .year)
dc.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let dob = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(from: dc)! 
// You could also use a DateFormatter to parse DOB from a string
let student1 = Student(numbers:["0773024962"], DOB:dob, gender:.male)
```

Comment: An option for the phone numbers could be `numbers.joined(separator:”,”)`

Comment: Thank you very for advise Pauw11. I used an array for PhoneNumber because users have multiple numbers. How to use Array for phone numbers/

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How to use joined(separator)

Comment: @BhanukaIsuru To clarify my previous comment, use joined when you want to get all phone numbers as a string